# Epic on FHIR Sandbox Clinician Login Issue

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, hl7-fhir, epic, smart-on-fhir

I'm having trouble logging in as a clinician to the Epic FHIR sandbox using the standalone OAuth 2.0 workflows. Every time I attempt to execute a GET request with the test user credentials FHIR and the password EpicFhir11!, I encounter a 404 not found error.

According to the documentation, my app should link (using HTTP GET) to the authorize endpoint and append specific query string parameters, including response_type, client_id, redirect_uri, scope, and aud. I've implemented this in my code and verified that the values are correct multiple times. However, I keep getting this error. Your assistance would be greatly appreciated.

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
// import { oauth2 as SMART } from 'fhirclient';

import { useLocation, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

import { physician_client_id, physician_redirect_uri, fhirServerBaseUrl } from '../secret';

const PhysicianLogin = () => {
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const location = useLocation();
    const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(location.search);
    let code = null;
    code = searchParams.get('code');

    const audience = fhirServerBaseUrl + '/';

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const authLink = `${fhirServerBaseUrl}/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&redirect_uri=${physician_redirect_uri}&client_id=${physician_client_id}&scope=openid%20fhirUser&aud=${audience}`;
        window.location.href = authLink;
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        if (code) {
            console.log({
                code: code,
            });

            const params = new URLSearchParams();
            params.append('grant_type', 'authorization_code');
            params.append('code', code);
            params.append('redirect_uri', physician_redirect_uri);
            params.append('client_id', physician_client_id);
            params.append('state', '1234');

            let tokenUrl = fhirServerBaseUrl +'/oauth2/token';

            fetch(tokenUrl, {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                    // Accept: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                },
                body: params,
                // body: JSON.stringify({
                //  grant_type: 'authorization_code',
                //  code: code,
                //  redirect_uri: redirect,
                //  client_id: clientId,
                // }),
            })
                .then((response) => response.json())
                .then((data) => {
                    if (data.access_token) {
                        localStorage.setItem('accessToken', data.access_token);
                        localStorage.setItem('patient', data.patient);
                        navigate('/physician');
                        // fetch(`https://fhir.epic.com/interconnect-fhir-oauth/api/FHIR/DSTU2/Patient/${this.patient}`)
                    }
                    console.log({
                        tokenData: data,
                    });
                });
        } else {
            console.log('no code');
        }
    }, []);
    return (
        <section>
            <div className='login-container'>
                <form action='' className='login-form' onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                    <div className='form-control'>
                        <input
                            type='submit'
                            value='Login with FHIR-epic'
                            className='btn-submit'
                        />
                        
                        >
                            Sign in with FHIR epic
                        </a> */}
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </section>
    );
};

export default PhysicianLogin;
```

I anticipated being able to sign in to the Epic sandbox with the clinician test account. I made sure that the client ID for non-production, the redirect URI, and the FHIR server base URL were all accurate. I also checked that the application's intended audience is clinicians and even attempted to log in using a different test user (FHIRTWO). I've contacted open@epic.com, and they directed me to get in touch with Vendor Services. I'm looking to sidestep any fees associated with Vendor Services if I can.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you aren't even getting to the user login screen, therefore something must be off about your initial call. A couple of things to try:

1. Be sure your redirect URI (down to capitalization, slashes, etc.) matches exactly with one of the redirect URIs in your app listing.
2. Make sure you've waited long enough (up to 12 hours) for your app and any changes you've made to it to sync to the sandbox environment.
3. It seems your `audience` is incorrect. You are setting it to `fhirServerBaseUrl + '/'`, which would make it `https://fhir.epic.com/interconnect-fhir-oauth/`. It should be `https://fhir.epic.com/interconnect-fhir-oauth/api/FHIR/R4` (or whichever FHIR version you are using if not R4).

If these don't work, please clarify what you are setting `fhirServerBaseUrl` to.

Comment: My redirect URI is set to http://localhost:5173/physician, which is exactly the same as what's listed in the app configuration. It has been over 12 hours since I last updated the app listing, so the changes should be in sync with the sandbox environment by now. Additionally, I've configured the 'fhirServerBaseUrl' as 'https://fhir.epic.com/interconnect-fhir-oauth'.

Comment: Did you fix the `audience` and retry?

Comment: I incorporated the audience fix and retried. Now I am getting a server error. Requested URL: /interconnect-fhir-oauth/oauth2/token. http 404

Comment: After updating the application to use the SMART on FHIR R4 version, the issue with invalid OAuth 2.0 requests persists. After entering the test credentials, the console displays a GET request to https://fhir.epic.com/interconnect-fhir-event/notificationservices/signalr... 404 Not Found error.

Comment: Okay, so it sounds like you now can get to the point of entering the credentials and obtaining an authorization code, but exchanging that code for an access token is failing. Your code snippet above shows that you are including `state` in the body of the POST call to the /token endpoint; this is not correct, `state` is not used in this step. While you're at it, if your app is a confidential client, make sure that you are passing the client ID and secret correctly in the header.

Comment: After omitting the 'state' parameter from the authLink variable, submitting the test credentials still results in a GET request to fhir.epic.com/interconnect-fhir-event/notificationservices/… that is met with a 404 Not Found error in the console. The application exclusively executes client-side calls without the engagement of a back-end server to manage the secure exchange of the authorization code for an access token. Consequently, the application lacks a web server component, classifying it as a public client rather than a confidential one within the OAuth 2.0 framework.